# Locate first occurance of line with SharpSVN?

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

Is there any easy way to determine which commit a specified line of a file was last modified, with SharpSVN?

Let's say I have the following three commits:

Commit 1:

```
Hello
```

Commit 2:

```
Hello, World!
```

Commit 3:

```
Hello, World!
Hi There :D
```

I'd be looking for some kind of function that does the following:

```
LastMod(lineNum: 1); //returns 2, since the first line was last modified in commit 2
LastMod(lineNum: 2); //returns 3, for the same reason
```

I'd need to do this on a rather large scale (large SVN repositories, with hundreds/thousands of lines per file) so just 'brute force' comparing each line from each previous commit probably wouldn't work. Not sure if SVN provides an implementation for what I'm looking for, I'm new to SVN and SharpSVN.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have no idea about SharpSVN, but I think I can help...

Subversion has a special command called `annotate` or `blame` or `praise`. What this command does is list out all the lines in a file, and show you when that last line was changed and by whom.

```
C> REM: produce an annotated report on foo.c#
C> svn blame foo.c#
```

This will produce a report that looks something like this (Well, not anything like this because this is munged Java code, but you get the idea):

```
109990     jevans package com.tc.cache.frontend;
109990     jevans 
109990     jevans import com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory;
109990     jevans import com.tangosol.net.NamedCache;
140072 dweintraub import java.util.ArrayList;
136130 ihroseline import java.util.List;
136130 ihroseline import java.util.Map;
123931     bfelds import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
109990     jevans import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

The first column is the revision where the line was changed and the second column is who changed the line. The rest is the source code line.

Not being a C# developer, I really can't help too much beyond that. However, SharpSVN has a class called [SvnBlameArgs](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/T_SharpSvn_SvnBlameArgs.htm) that looks like it might do the same thing. There's also a [SvnBlameEventArgs](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/T_SharpSvn_SvnBlameEventArgs.htm) class.

There's also a [Blame](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/Overload_SharpSvn_SvnClient_Blame.htm) method that's part of the SvnClient class. I am willing to bet that the `SvnBlame` method is a way of producing that same type of report I showed you above.

Sorry I can't help beyond this...

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that, and try it out tomorrow (away from my computer right now).

Comment: Actually, just tried it and it worked perfectly :) client.GetBlame(target, out blame); to a Collection of SvnBlameEventArgs did exactly what I wanted to happen. Thanks again :)